# delete only archived data from bi-temporal collection

Tags: marklogic, bi-temporal

MarkLogic version : 9.0-6.2

I'm using bi-temporal data Management, and want to delete (physical delete not logical delete)only archive data which are older than 2 months from temporal collection.And latest version of document should be retained in latest collection.

I have tried temporal:document-delete, which removes latest version of document from latest collection and only logically deleting the documents.

And temporal:document-wipe deletes all version of document. But I want to retain the recent version in latest collection and physically delete only the archived versions which are older than 2 months.

Answer (score 0):

See the "Updates and deletes outside the temporal functions" at

https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/229/0/managing-and-updating-temporal-documents